# Biblatex Display the Review Section

Tags: biblatex, formatting

For assignment I am writing I need to write a brief review of each reference and have it in the references section (indented by one tab on left hand side and blank line to next reference} after the reference itself.  It is for me to justify why included this reference in the assignment.

With biblatex how can I a new field - ie 'Review' after each reference in the Bibliogrphy.

References
CTAN 2006 ....
    Can this be added in Reference Section

...

Is there a field I can use to do this or is this best done some other way?

Here is the basic biblatex schema I use.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reference.bib}
@Online{ctan,
    Title                    = {CTAN},
    Url                      = {http://www.ctan.org},
    Year                     = {2006},
    Subtitle                 = {The {Comprehensive TeX Archive Network}},
    Urldate                  = {2006-10-01},
    Label                    = {CTAN},
    Review                   = {Can this be added in Reference Section}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    urlseen = {accessed on},
}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\begin{document}
\citet{CTAN}
\printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what exactly it is you want. Can you explain it in more detail and maybe add a mock-up of the output you expect to see?

Comment: You can use the `abstract` field and something like `\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\setunit{\par}\printfield{abstract}\finentry}`.

Comment: @moewe - Yes \renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\setunit{\par}\printfield{abstract}\vspace{\parskip}\finentry}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}.  Does pretty much what I want.  Is there a way to add vertical space before the abstract field is displayed?.  I can use the \bibitemsep for space after but would like to seperate more at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no review field, but you can use the `abstract` field. By default it is not shown in the bibliography, but with

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\setunit{\smallskip\par}\printfield{abstract}\finentry}
```

it is.

You can use `\medskip` or `\bigskip` (or other skips) instead of `\smallskip` for larger space between the `abstract` and the rest of the entry.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238554/ . Alternatively, using plain Bibtex you can use the `note` field, which is likely to be displayed at the end of a reference.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for the link, I had forgotten that one. With `biblatex`, `note` is probably not that good an idea, there the `note` field comes even before the publisher, `addendum` might be a better idea here, but the back-references will be placed after the `addendum`. I just checked `plain.bst` though, there `note` comes at the end.