# Present reference in a table

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

**Update 1**
I use biblatex and bibber to create my bibliography. the reference section contain a list of the articles referenced. How can the reference section be changed that the reference appear in table. Is the reference section by hand the corresponding latex code will look like

```
\section{Reference}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{||c|X||}\hline\hline
    cite1 & Title, author etc\\ \hline 
    cite2 & Title, author etc\\ \hline 
    cite3 & Title, author etc\\ \hline \hline   
\end{tabularx}
```

The string citeX can be the normal string [citeX] , or of the form X.Y.Z where X,Y,Z are number.

**Update 2 (and 3)**

From [style=authoryear extra block in front of bibliography list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266507/style-authoryear-extra-block-in-front-of-bibliography-list) the MWE is modified to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp, bibstyle=authortitle, sorting=nyt, dashed=false,%
    maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter

% user-level command for printing tabular bibliography
\let\printbibtabular\printbibliography
\patchcmd{\printbibtabular}{\blx@printbibliography}{\bbx@printbibtabular}{}{}
\patchcmd{\printbibtabular}{\blx@printbibliography}    {\bbx@printbibtabular}{}{}
\let\bbx@printbibtabular\blx@printbibliography
\patchcmd{\bbx@printbibtabular}{\blx@bibliography}{\bbx@bibtabular}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbx@printbibtabular}
  {\def\blx@theenv{bibliography}}{\def\blx@theenv{bibtabular}}{}{}

% underlying macros
\def\bbx@bibtabular#1{%
  \blx@bibheading\blx@theheading\blx@thetitle
  \blx@bibnote\blx@theprenote
  \begingroup
  \blx@bibinit
  \let\@noitemerr\@empty
  \let\blx@noitem\blx@warn@bibempty
  \ifnum\bibinitsep=\z@
    \let\blx@initsep\relax
  \fi
  \ifnum\bibnamesep=\z@
    \let\blx@namesep\relax
  \fi
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibinit}%
  % copy filtered list of entries to internal list macro
  \def\blx@do##1{%
    \blx@ifdata{##1}{%
      \begingroup
      \blx@getdata{##1}
      \blx@bibcheck
      \iftoggle{blx@skipentry}{}{%
        \global\let\blx@noitem\@empty
        \listadd\blx@tempa{##1}}%
      \endgroup}{}}
  \let\blx@done\relax
  \blx@listloop{#1}
  % tabular output for each item in list macro
  \def\do##1{\bbx@tab@label{##1} & \bbx@tab@item{##1} \\ \hline}
  \csuse{blx@env@\blx@theenv}%
  \dolistloop{\blx@tempa}
  \csuse{blx@endenv@\blx@theenv}%
  \blx@bibnote\blx@thepostnote
  \endgroup}

\def\bbx@tab@label#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata{#1}%
  \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \blx@thelabelnumber
  \blx@addprefixnumber
  \addtocounter{instcount}\@ne
  \csuse{bbx@tabenv@\blx@theenv}\relax
  \endgroup}

\def\bbx@tab@item#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata{#1}%
  \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \csuse{blx@item@\blx@theenv}\relax
  \blx@initsep
  \blx@namesep
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibitem}%
  \blx@execute
  \blx@initunit
  \blx@anchor
  \blx@beglang
  \bibsentence
  \blx@pagetracker
  \blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@postpunct
  \blx@endlang
  \endgroup}

% user-level command for defining tabular bibliography format
\newrobustcmd*{\defbibtabular}[5]{%
  \long\csdef{blx@env@#1}{#2}%
  \long\csdef{blx@endenv@#1}{#3}%
  \long\csdef{bbx@tabenv@#1}{#4}%
  \long\csdef{blx@item@#1}{#5}}

\makeatother

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{bibcite}{%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\addspace}}
         {\printnames{labelname}%
          \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.8\textwidth}|}\hline}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\usebibmacro{bibcite}}
  {}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{sigfridsson, geer, nussbaum, worman, knuth:ct:b, knuth:ct:c}.

\printbibtabular

\end{document}
```

the modification is

```
\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.8\textwidth}|}\hline}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\usebibmacro{bibcite}}
  {}
```

and see comment of Guido

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What  you're trying to do is not quite clear to me. Is it a bibliography?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? In any case, whatever you are really trying to do, we need a complete minimal working example which shows your setup and includes some sample `.bib` entries. When we compile the code you post, we should reproduce a minimal version of your current bibliography. The thing to then do is to tell us what needs to be changed in how it looks and not how you think that might be achieved, because there may be alternatives to a table which you've not considered.

Comment: To create latex file that satisfy a msword template (not my choice of reference style). I will learn about bst file and create MWE.

Comment: Biblatex/Biber doesn't use `.bst` files.

Comment: This is the default behaviour. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
`

Comment: Here are two questions of similar nature: [How to change the format of biblatex references to have 3 columns (alpha, author, 'Titel and other information')?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307830)/ and [tabular bibliography with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71088)

Comment: `biblatex` does not set the bibliography in a tabular environment by default, what you get with the `numeric` and `alphabetic` styles might come very close to what you want, though (minus the horizontal and vertical lines, which I would find rather distracting and very unusual in a bibliography). It is possible (with quite some effort) to get a "tabular" bibliography, see in addition to  Torbjørn's links, [style=authoryear extra block in front of bibliography list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266507/35864), ...

Comment: ... [Tabular bibliography with 2 cols for `@inbook`, `@article` etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157359/35864), [Align/avoid numeration and labels in a custom biblatex format](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79001/35864)

Comment: Does changing the line `\def\do##1{\bbx@tab@label{##1} & \bbx@tab@item{##1} \\}` to `\def\do##1{\bbx@tab@label{##1} & \bbx@tab@item{##1} \\ \hline}` help

Comment: Are you *really* sure you are supposed to add those lines? I would make sure before going into all the trouble of adding them.

Comment: Thanx, solved. it is a strange request I agree and not my personal preference but is needed.

Comment: @Johan If you found a solution, please do **not** add it to the place reserved for the question, just write a **self answer**, that is welcome here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of comments received

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp, bibstyle=authortitle, sorting=nyt, dashed=false,%
    maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter

% user-level command for printing tabular bibliography
\let\printbibtabular\printbibliography
\patchcmd{\printbibtabular}{\blx@printbibliography}{\bbx@printbibtabular}{}{}
\patchcmd{\printbibtabular}{\blx@printbibliography}    {\bbx@printbibtabular}{}{}
\let\bbx@printbibtabular\blx@printbibliography
\patchcmd{\bbx@printbibtabular}{\blx@bibliography}{\bbx@bibtabular}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbx@printbibtabular}
  {\def\blx@theenv{bibliography}}{\def\blx@theenv{bibtabular}}{}{}

% underlying macros
\def\bbx@bibtabular#1{%
  \blx@bibheading\blx@theheading\blx@thetitle
  \blx@bibnote\blx@theprenote
  \begingroup
  \blx@bibinit
  \let\@noitemerr\@empty
  \let\blx@noitem\blx@warn@bibempty
  \ifnum\bibinitsep=\z@
    \let\blx@initsep\relax
  \fi
  \ifnum\bibnamesep=\z@
    \let\blx@namesep\relax
  \fi
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibinit}%
  % copy filtered list of entries to internal list macro
  \def\blx@do##1{%
    \blx@ifdata{##1}{%
      \begingroup
      \blx@getdata{##1}
      \blx@bibcheck
      \iftoggle{blx@skipentry}{}{%
        \global\let\blx@noitem\@empty
        \listadd\blx@tempa{##1}}%
      \endgroup}{}}
  \let\blx@done\relax
  \blx@listloop{#1}
  % tabular output for each item in list macro
  \def\do##1{\bbx@tab@label{##1} & \bbx@tab@item{##1} \\ \hline}
  \csuse{blx@env@\blx@theenv}%
  \dolistloop{\blx@tempa}
  \csuse{blx@endenv@\blx@theenv}%
  \blx@bibnote\blx@thepostnote
  \endgroup}

\def\bbx@tab@label#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata{#1}%
  \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \blx@thelabelnumber
  \blx@addprefixnumber
  \addtocounter{instcount}\@ne
  \csuse{bbx@tabenv@\blx@theenv}\relax
  \endgroup}

\def\bbx@tab@item#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata{#1}%
  \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \csuse{blx@item@\blx@theenv}\relax
  \blx@initsep
  \blx@namesep
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibitem}%
  \blx@execute
  \blx@initunit
  \blx@anchor
  \blx@beglang
  \bibsentence
  \blx@pagetracker
  \blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@postpunct
  \blx@endlang
  \endgroup}

% user-level command for defining tabular bibliography format
\newrobustcmd*{\defbibtabular}[5]{%
  \long\csdef{blx@env@#1}{#2}%
  \long\csdef{blx@endenv@#1}{#3}%
  \long\csdef{bbx@tabenv@#1}{#4}%
  \long\csdef{blx@item@#1}{#5}}

\makeatother

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{bibcite}{%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\addspace}}
         {\printnames{labelname}%
          \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.8\textwidth}|}\hline}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\usebibmacro{bibcite}}
  {}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{sigfridsson, geer, nussbaum, worman, knuth:ct:b, knuth:ct:c}.

\printbibtabular

\end{document}
```