# Cite special document type (exhibition catalogue) in a special way with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm trying to typeset my spouse's art history dissertation thesis. In general, her university requires her to

- provide citations in footnotes, `authoryear-ibid`-style
- have a tabular bibliography, with the `authoryear` short form in the first column and the extended bibliographic entry in the second. (The entries must be sorted by the first column, the importance of which will be clearer in a moment.)

However, one special type of cited documents are exhibition catalogues (or "Ausstellungskataloge"), and these need to be cited quite differently. Instead of

`<name> <year>`,

the citation footnote must look like

`Ausst.-Kat. <location>[/<2nd location>] <year>`.

This same information must also replace the `authoryear` short form in the first column of the bibliography.

So, in essence I'd like to achieve the following for the document type exhibition catalogue:

1. Utilise a tabular bibliography with citation short forms in the first column
2. Replace the usual `authoryear` short form by `Ausst.-Kat. <location>[/<2nd location>] <year>` and use this in citation footnotes and the first column of the tabular bibliography
3. Have the entire bibliography be sorted by the first column with the respective short forms, so that any exhibition catalogue, irrespective of its author/editor name or title (!), will be listed before a book/article penned by an author whose name starts with, say, "B"
4. An exhibition catalogue's long entry should comprise 
   `<exhibition title> [<subtitle>], hg. v. <editor's first name(s)> <editor's second name(s)> (Ausst.-Kat. <exhibition location>, <museum's name>, <exhibition dates> [; <2nd location>, <museum's name>, <exhibition dates>]), <address> <year>`.

My question is: Is there a way to get this to work automatically?

Below I include a minimum *non-working* example where I try to approximate very crudely some of the points above. It fails in that it's not automated, and it naturally ignores point 3 in my list entirely (the exhibition catalogue's entry should come second, between Augustinus and Bernardini, in the bibliography instead of third).

Here's the MNWEB:

```
\documentclass[12pt, paper=a4]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{avant}      % Set sans serif font: helvet,avant,...

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
    autocite=footnote,
    bibstyle=authortitle,
    isbn=false,
    maxcitenames=3]
{biblatex}

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\newlength{\citelabelwidth}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\begingroup\defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}\usebibmacro{cite}\endgroup}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\citelabelwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \blx@setlabwidth{\citelabelwidth}{\usebibmacro{cite}}
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @Book{Augustinus1955,
        Title                    = {Vom Gottesstaat},
        Author                   = {Augustinus, Aurelius},
        Year                     = {1955},
        Address                  = {Zürich},
        Volume                   = {1},
        ISBN                     = {978-3-423-34393-0},
        Translator               = {Thimme, Wilhelm}}
    @Book{Bernardini1999,
        Title                    = {Gian Lorenzo Bernini regista del barocco},
        Editor                   = {Bernardini, Maria Grazia and Fagiolo dell'Arco, Marcello},
        Year                     = {1999},
        Address                  = {Mailand},
        Abstract                 = {Il volume, che costituisce il catalogo dell'esposizione di Roma (Palazzo Esposizioni 24 marzo-31 maggio 1999) vuole anche essere la completa e aggiornata monografia su Gian Lorenzo Bernini e si pone come uno strumento indispensabile per la conoscenza dell'arte barocca italiana. I saggi, curati da vari esperti del Bernini (tra cui M. Fagiolo, I. Faldi, O. Ferrari, C.L. Frommel, P. Marconi, V. Martinelli, R. Preimesberger, M. Winner) analizzano la vasta produzione berniniana.},
        ISBN                     = {978-88-8118-484-2},
        Keywords                 = {Art / History / Baroque \& Rococo}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Mein erstes Kapitel}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\autocite{Bernardini1999}
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\footnote{Ausst.-Kat. Bonn/Berlin 2005--2006.}
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.\autocite[][S. 130]{Augustinus1955}

\printbibliography

\noindent\begin{tabular}{l p{11cm}}
    Ausst.-Kat. Bonn/Berlin 2005--2006 & Barock im Vatikan. Kunst und Kultur der Päpste II 1572--1676, hg. v. Jutta Frings (Ausst.-Kat. Bonn, Kunst- und Ausstellungshalle der Bundesrepublik Deutschland, 25. November bis 19. März 2006; Berlin, Martin-Gropius-Bau, 12. April bis 10. Julia 2006), Leipzig 2006
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here's another MWEB, based on the `biblatex-archaeologie` style (which was recommended in the comments) - it automatically gets 1) the information in the citation and 2) the (tabular) bibliography entries' order right, doesn't allow for footnote citations and *ibidem* abbreviations, however:

```
\documentclass[12pt, paper=a4]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{avant}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=archaeologie,
    width=7cm,
    isbn=false,
    maxcitenames=3]%
{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @Book{Augustinus1955,
        Title                    = {Vom Gottesstaat},
        Author                   = {Augustinus, Aurelius},
        Year                     = {1955},
        Address                  = {Zürich},
        Volume                   = {1},
        ISBN                     = {978-3-423-34393-0},
        Translator               = {Thimme, Wilhelm}}
    @Book{Bernardini1999,
        Title                    = {Gian Lorenzo Bernini regista del barocco},
        Editor                   = {Bernardini, Maria Grazia and Fagiolo dell'Arco, Marcello},
        Year                     = {1999},
        Address                  = {Mailand},
        ISBN                     = {978-88-8118-484-2},
        Keywords                 = {Art / History / Baroque \& Rococo}}
    @reference{Frings2005,
        editor                                   = {Frings, Jutta},
        title                                        = {Barock im Vatikan. Kunst und Kultur der Päpste II 1572--1676},
        shorthand                                = {Ausst.-Kat. Bonn/Berlin 2005--2006},
        series                                   = {(Ausst.-Kat. Bonn, Kunst- und Ausstellungshalle der Bundesrepublik Deutschland, 25. November bis 19. März 2006; Berlin, Martin-Gropius-Bau, 12. April bis 10. Juli 2006)},
        location                                 = {Leipzig},
        year                                         = {2005}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Mein erstes Kapitel}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\parencite{Bernardini1999}
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\parencite{Frings2005}
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.\parencite[][S. 130]{Augustinus1955}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: offtopic: what does MNWEB/MWEB stand for?

Comment: For your catalogues it might be the cleanest solution to create a new entry type, see [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864) for help on that. Tabular bibliographies aren't easy: [tabular bibliography with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71088/35864), but lists (of shorthands for example) are slightly easier. You might want to check out some of Maïeul Rouquette's `biblatex` packages: https://www.ctan.org/author/rouquette, I have the hunch that he has done something in that direction.

Comment: The [`biblatex-archaeologie`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/archaeologie) style also has some features that could lead you to a solution.

Comment: @naphaneal A MWEB is a minimum working example with a bibliography.

Comment: @moewe Thank you very much, `biblatex-archaeologie` looks like a very promising start, in that the bibliography is tabular and sorted by shorthands!
Unfortunately, though, the style really only has one specific citation style which differs greatly from the one I need (it lacks, e.g., footnote citations, and _ibidem_ abbreviations). Can you think of a way one could have both functionalities?

Comment: Why yes of course, but if you have a look at `archaeologie` you'll see that this can require quite some code and so a full solution might well be beyond the scope of this site. But I will see if there is a reasonable solution to what you want.

Comment: @moewe Thank you for thinking this over, much appreciated!

Comment: Note that `Keywords = {Art / History / Baroque \& Rococo}` probably won't work as expected, use `Keywords = {art, history, baroque, rococo}` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

> Since this question has been answered poorly below, the decision was made to turn this question into a new `biblatex-style arthistory-bonn`.
>
> The biblatex-style is published with CTAN:
>   https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-arthistory-bonn
>
> The development of the code is done at GitHub https://github.com/LukasCBossert/biblatex-arthistory.

---

Ok, this is rather a dirty hack, but it should meet the requirements, if you want to use `biblatex-archaeologie`:

1. citing in footnotes. I simply added a new `\cite`-command which is `\footcite`:

   `\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
     {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
     {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
     \usebibmacro{cite}}%
     {\multicitedelim}%
     {\ifboolexpr{%
     test{\ifbool{bbx:inreferences}}%
     and%
     test{\ifentrytype{inreference}}%
     }{}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}}%`

   Now you can cite with `\footcite[123]{bibtex-key}`
2. the `ibid-issue`. Unfortunately we havn't inserted that into the style `archaeologie`, so I copy/paste  the code from `authoryear-ibid.cbx`.

I give you the full MWEB:

```
\documentclass[12pt, paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{libertine}%more fonts (e.g. bold letters)

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=archaeologie,
    width=4cm,
    isbn=false,
    ibidtracker=constrict,
    translation,
    maxcitenames=3]
{biblatex}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}}%
  {\multicitedelim}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
  test{\ifbool{bbx:inreferences}}%
  and%
  test{\ifentrytype{inreference}}%
  }{}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}}%


%%-- from authoryear-ibid.cbx
\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}{\iflastcitekey}

\newbool{cbx:parens}
\newbool{cbx:loccit}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{ibidpage}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=constrict}}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=false}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{citeyear}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
          {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{label}}}}



\newbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
  \ifbool{cbx:loccit}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{postnote}\OR\boolean{cbx:loccit}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibcloseparen}
       {}}
        {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\postnotedelim}
       {\extpostnotedelim\bibopenparen}%
     \printfield{postnote}\bibcloseparen}}


\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @Book{Augustinus1955,
    Title                    = {Vom Gottesstaat},
    Author                   = {Augustinus, Aurelius},
    Year                     = {1955},
    location                  = {Zürich},
    keywords = {Quelle},
    origlanguage={latin},
    number                   = {1},
    ISBN                     = {978-3-423-34393-0},
    translator               = {Thimme, Wilhelm}
    }

 @Book{Bernardini1999,
        Title                    = {Gian Lorenzo Bernini regista del barocco},
        Editor                   = {Bernardini, Maria Grazia and Fagiolo dell'Arco, Marcello},
        Year                     = {1999},
        location                  = {Mailand},
        ISBN                     = {978-88-8118-484-2},
        Keywords                 = {Art / History / Baroque \& Rococo}}

@book{AusstellungBonn2005,
    title = {Barock im Vatikan},
    subtitle = {Kunst und Kultur der Päpste II 1572--1676},
     shorthand = {Ausst.-Kat. Bonn/Berlin 2005--2006},
     editor = {Jutta Frings},
     keywords = {Ausstellung},
     titleaddon = {\parentext{Ausst.-Kat. Bonn, Kunst- und Ausstellungshalle         der Bundesrepublik Deutschland, 25. November bis 19. März 2006; Berlin, Martin-Gropius-Bau, 12. April bis 10. Juli 2006}},
     location = {Leipzig},
     year = {2006},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}  
\begin{document}

\chapter{Mein erstes Kapitel}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing     elit.\footcite{Bernardini1999}\footcite[23]{Bernardini1999}
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae,     felis.\footcite{AusstellungBonn2005}
\footcite{AusstellungBonn2005}
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.\footcite[][\pno\ 130]    {Augustinus1955}\footcite[][\pno\ 130]{Augustinus1955}


\printbibheading[%
    heading=bibliography,% 
    title={Bibliographie}] 

\printbibliography[%
    keyword=Quelle,%
    heading=subbibliography,
    title={Antike Quelle}]

\printbibliography[%
    keyword=Ausstellung,%
    heading=subbibliography, 
    title={Ausstellungskataloge}]

\printbibliography[%
    notkeyword=Ausstellung,%
    notkeyword=Quelle,%
    heading=subbibliography,
     title={Sekundärliteratur}]

\end{document}
```

---

`ibid` does not work now when it is a `shorthand` (like the case with ›Ausstellungskatalog‹).
But maybe @moewe has some ideas how to make this code better.

Comment: @moewe it may need some revision

Comment: If you really just copied `authoryear-ibid.cbx`, it might be easier to go with `bibstyle=archaeologie, citestyle=authoryear-ibid` instead and only apply the necessary modifications later. I'm not sure why you would use `\pno` in some of the cite commands. You can give "ibid" preference over the shorthand by changing the logic in `\newbibmacro*{cite}` & `\newbibmacro*{textcite}`. Right now the first check is for shorthand and the second for "ibid".

Comment: I consider the current approach a bit of an abuse of the shorthand field. A conceptually nicer (but admittedly more laborious) solution would define a new entry type for catalogues. The downside of that approach is that it would require a dedicated bit in the cite bibmacro (since the citations are not author-year).

Comment: @moewe you are right. We are coding this issue for  a new style (biblatex-arthistory) to meet the requirements, see GitHub.