# Bibliography in 3 columns

Tags: bibliographies, columns

My bibliography should look like this:
[image]

Could someone tell me how do I get 3 columns?
This is my code:

```
    %Dokumentklasse
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, pointlessnumbers,  twoside, numbers=noenddot, captions=nooneline]{scrreprt}

%===Modifizierungen Inhaltsverzeichnis===%
\usepackage{tocloft} 

%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{#1}{\uppercase{#1}}{}{}% 
%\makeatother 


%===Standard Packages===%
%Umlaute, etc.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% zusätzliche Schriftzeichen der American Mathematical Society
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% ============= Dokumentbeginn =============

\begin{document}

\include{01_titel}

\include{02_danksagungen}

\include{03_aufgabenstellung}


\tableofcontents

% pagestyle für gesamtes Dokument aktivieren
%\pagestyle{fancy}


\include{04_einleitung}

\include{05_grundlagen}

\include{06_konstruktionsprozess}

\include{07_methoden}

\include{08_ergebnisse}

\include{09_diskussion}

%===Abbildungsverzeichnis===%
\listoffigures


%===Tabellenverzeichnis===%
\listoftables


%===Literaturverzeichnis===%
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\bibliography{Literatur}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is **not** compilable! Please make it compilable for us; your  included files are missing for us.  And please add three entries of your bib file to your question (then we can test the resulting bibliography you need ...)  At last that is called a minimal working example (MWE).  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: For the close-queue: I typed up a quick answer just now, so if you want to leave the question open that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on my `biblatex-ext-tabular` package, which is part of [`biblatex-ext`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf). The code was originally inspired and largely taken from [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s answer to [tabular bibliography with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71088/35864).

Of course this approach requires `biblatex` instead of BibTeX, but that should hopefully be an acceptable requirement.

With `\defbibtabular` we define our new three-column tabular bibliography. Before we can do that we need a small auxiliary macro `tabular:labelnumber` that prints the citation label as in a normal numeric bibliography.

The first two arguments to `\defbibtabular{bibtabular}` set up the beginning and the end of the environment and are more or less straightforward. The third argument sets up the code for each line in the bibliography. The macros `tabular:sortname` and `tabular:omitsortname` were specifically designed to allow for the primary/sort-names to be distributed over two columns.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\newbibmacro{tabular:labelnumber}{%
  \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{%
   @{}
   L{\dimexpr0.05\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
   L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
   L{\dimexpr0.65\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
   @{}}}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{\usebibmacro{tabular:labelnumber}} &
   \anchorlang{\usebibmacro{tabular:sortname}} &
   \driver{\usebibmacro{tabular:omitsortname}} \\}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,geer,gaonkar:in}
\printbibtabular
\end{document}
```

[image: A tabular bibliography: The first column contains the citation label in the form "[1]", the second column the primary/sort name "Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf", the third column contains the rest of the bibliographic information.]